# Twitter widget not working, only gives me a link that says Tweets by xxx

Tags: html, twitter, widget

This is the code that twitter gave me. in the generator it looks fine but when I load the page with the code in my HTML it only shows as a text saying Tweets by ViktorParment.

```
    <section class="inner-wrapper">
    <article id="tablet">
        <img src="img/hand_ipad.png">
    </article>
    <aside id="tablet2">
        <h2>Twitter</h2>
        <a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="500" data-height="600" href="https://twitter.com/ViktorParment">Tweets by ViktorParment</a> <script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </aside>
</section>
```

[What it looks like on the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7irL.png)

Comment: Please explain further. Where's the code?

Comment: i updated it now! sorry for the bad post :)

Comment: It works when i look at it in the preview now....